# A simpler axiom for "induction" in untyped lambda calculus

Tags: axioms, formal-proofs, lambda-calculus

I'm working on a weird proof system involving reductions in the lambda calculus. I'm thinking of including the following axiom:

```
forall h q s y.


(λg → g g (q s)) (λ f x → h (f f ∘ q ∘ y) x)
===
(λg → g g s) (λ f x → h (f f ∘ y) (q x))
```

where `∘` is function composition (and has lower precedence than function application)

Are there some simpler axioms (possibly none at all) I could use instead from which this statement could be proven?

Is there a problem I don't see with making this an axiom?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this axiom? Where does this axiom come from?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't yet have a coherent enough explanation of what I'm trying to do to answer that except to say that I'm calling it "induction" for a reason. I was hoping to just post this without context and see what people have to say.

Comment: Is there some relation with fixed point combinators?

Comment: Could you give us a few more basic clues about your proof system? Do lambda expressions represent propositions? Does the syntax you've used represent a deduction rule? (From the expression above the line, deduce the expression below the line?)

Comment: @Karl Yes, yes, and yes
I'm still working on formulating a better explanation. Sorry